# SQL comparing data in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that stores user's points in reading and writing and the point needed to meet the requirements for each user. Here's an example:

```
User | READING_PNTS | READING_REQ | WRITING_PNTS | WRITING_REQ
jim  |      3       |      8      |      6       |     5
tim  |      7       |      4      |      6       |     3
kim  |      7       |      5      |      2       |     5
Ron  |      6       |      4      |      8       |     4
Dom  |      10      |      7      |      6       |     3
ton  |      3       |      5      |      6       |     5
```

My resulting table should be simply the number of ppl who meet both requirements and the number of ppl who don't meet both requirements. So in this case it would be this:

```
Meet | Not Meet
 3   |  3
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm working in Access for the record. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation, which in MS Access uses `iif()` or `swtich()`:

```
select sum(iif(reading_pnts >= reading_req and writing_pnts >= writing_req, 1, 0)) as meet,
       sum(iif(reading_pnts >= reading_req and writing_pnts >= writing_req, 0, 1)) as not_meet
from t;
```